# Finding a user by ID inside a collection.allow behaving very strangely in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I only want to allow a user to insert a document when his email is verified, I wrote the following code.

```
Events.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        var user = Meteor.users.find({_id: userId});
        console.log(user); // logs a large object
        // if the user's email is verified
        if (user.emails[0].verified) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Running this, I get an error, `"internal server error"`, looking at the server, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, which means that something is wrong with my user object. So I logged the object, and instead of seeing a user, I get a huge object, abbreviated below:

```
{ _mongo:
    // lots of stuff
}
```

I think that's the top level mongoDB object that Meteor uses.

How in the world is `Meteor.users.find({_id: userId})` returning the MongoDB object instead of the user I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `findOne`, and not `find`. `find` returns a cursor to the result, `findOne` returns the first matched document.